Excel VSTO Add-In: Task Pane Not Displaying When Button Clicked

Question: Excel VSTO Add-In: Task Pane Not Displaying When Button Clicked

I am a beginner Excel programmer. I successfully created a customized Excel ribbon (COM-AddIn) that loads into excel. It was easy enough. I then decided to add a 'User Control' in order to create a task pane. The task pane should show if the button 'Show Task Pane' is pressed, and sure enough that does not happen. I have stepped through the code, and I do not see any 'null' values. I have placed a few message boxes (since removed) to check show specific values and ensure all parts of the code are being reached. There are no erros, and no warnings.
Architecture:
Visual Studio 2022 - Community edition
VSTO
.Net 4.8
Microsoft Office 365 (Excel)
Very similar questions that have not helped me resolve my issue:

Excel Custom Task Pane not showing
Should a parent window be assigned to a custom task pane for a VSTO for Excel Add-in?

I am going to share all my code since the code base is small enough:
Ribbon1.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;

namespace ExcelAddIn1
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Ribbon1 : Office.IRibbonExtensibility
    {
        private Office.IRibbonUI ribbon;

        public Ribbon1()
        {
        }

        #region IRibbonExtensibility Members

        public string GetCustomUI(string ribbonID)
        {
            return GetResourceText("ExcelAddIn1.Ribbon1.xml");
        }

        #endregion

        #region Ribbon Callbacks
        //Create callback methods here. For more information about adding callback methods, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=271226

        public void Ribbon_Load(Office.IRibbonUI ribbonUI)
        {
            this.ribbon = ribbonUI;
        }

        #endregion

        public void OnShowTaskPaneClick(Office.IRibbonControl control)
        {
            // Show the task pane when the button is clicked
            Globals.ThisAddIn.ShowTaskPane();
        }

        public void OnRefreshDataClick(Office.IRibbonControl control)
        {

        }

        public System.Drawing.Bitmap GetImage(Office.IRibbonControl control)
        {
            Assembly currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            Stream imageStream = currentAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ExcelAddIn1.icons8-database-80.png");
            return new System.Drawing.Bitmap(imageStream);
        }

        #region Helpers

        private static string GetResourceText(string resourceName)
        {
            Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            string[] resourceNames = asm.GetManifestResourceNames();
            for (int i = 0; i < resourceNames.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (string.Compare(resourceName, resourceNames[i], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                {
                    using (StreamReader resourceReader = new StreamReader(asm.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceNames[i])))
                    {
                        if (resourceReader != null)
                        {
                            return resourceReader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}

MyTaskPaneControleDesigner.cs
namespace ExcelAddIn1
{
    partial class MyTaskPaneControl
    {
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // MyTaskPaneControl
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.Name = "MyTaskPaneControl";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 400);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
        }
    }
}

MyTaskPaneControl.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ExcelAddIn1
{
    public partial class MyTaskPaneControl : UserControl
    {
        public MyTaskPaneControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}

ThisAddin.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ExcelAddIn1
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private Ribbon1 ribbon;
        public Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane myTaskPane; // Declare the task pane here

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // Initialize the task pane
            MyTaskPaneControl taskPaneControl = new MyTaskPaneControl();
            myTaskPane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(taskPaneControl, "My Task Pane");
            myTaskPane.Visible = false; // Initially hidden
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
        {
            ribbon = new Ribbon1();
            return ribbon;
        }

        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion

        // Method to show the task pane
        public void ShowTaskPane()
        {
            myTaskPane.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}

Ribbon.xml
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab id="customTab" label="Analytics">
                <group id="group1" label="Beisbol Analytics">
                    <box id="box1" boxStyle="horizontal">
                        <splitButton id="helpSplitButton" size="large">
                            <button id="helpButton" label="Help" showLabel="true" />
                            <menu id="helpMenu">
                                <button id="helpOption" label="Help" onAction="OnHelpClick" />
                                <button id="aboutOption" label="About" onAction="OnAboutClick" />
                            </menu>
                        </splitButton>
                    </box>
                    <separator id="separator1" />
                    <box id="box2" boxStyle="horizontal">
                        <button id="refreshDataButton"
                                label="Refresh Data"
                                onAction="OnRefreshDataClick"
                                getImage="GetImage"
                                size="large"
                                showImage="true"
                                showLabel="true" />
                    </box>
                    <box id="box3" boxStyle="horizontal">
                        <button id="showTaskPaneButton"
                                label="Show Task Pane"
                                onAction="OnShowTaskPaneClick"
                                size="large"
                                showLabel="true" />
                    </box>
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>

